# From oracle to mySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have to remove all the tables which start with 'USER_' for oracle and mySQl:

For Oracle I did like that:

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN ( SELECT table_name FROM user_tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'USER_%' )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || c.table_name;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

What should it be in mySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mySQL, you do like that:

```
  SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE `',t.table_schema,'`.`',t.table_name,'`;') AS stmt
       FROM information_schema.tables t WHERE
         t.table_name LIKE 'USER_%%' ESCAPE '\\'
         ORDER BY t.table_name
```

This returns only the drop queries!